# Как открыть Serial Port на arduino вне Setup

Tags: arduino, микроконтроллеры

Есть лед-куб 4х4х4 с готовой прошивкой. В прошивке задействованные все порты. Нужно как-то сделать связь з пк через Serial port. При это порт RX TX не работает. Есть такая идея: поставить таймер который каждую секунду будет делать прерывание, которое открывать порт, принимать сообщение и закрывать порт. Так все это дело в теории занимает мало времени и глаз не заметит, что светодиод моргнул. Так имеем что-то такое:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
   message=Serial.read();
}
Serial.end();
```

Одна проблема. Оно не работает. Что можете посоветовать? Что не правильно?

Comment: Как именно не работает? В ``if`` заходит?

Comment: Глаз заметит, поэтому рецепт один - использовать другой микроконтроллер.

Comment: Переделывать железо и прошивку так, чтобы высвободить пару линий для коммуникации с компьютером.